# Using SED to update .htaccess with blocked IP addresses

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed

I have a file that has a list of "bad" IP addresses. I want to import this file of bad IP addresses into my `.htaccess` file to deny access via apache.

I want to automate this process using `sed`. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Nothing (ok, nothing much) to do with sys administration.

Comment: I have a file that contains some bad ip address , and i want to automate the process to add those ip to .htaccess for denying. Is it not a part of system administration ?

Comment: your question doesn't actually mention that - we're not mind readers. Anyhow, whilst that might be the exact usage scenario, the question itself is about using `sed`.

Comment: I have updated your question for you, as now it's about a thousand times more relevant and is a lot easier for people to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making question relevent , i will take care from next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `.htaccess` template with "%BANNED_IP_LIST%" in place where that list should be and use something like `sed -e "s/%BANNED_IP_LIST%/$(cat banned.txt)/"` to create actual `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I never used .htaccess template, let me try

Answer (score 3):

Why sed? Use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).
It can be configured to work with many different services, including Apache.